# Cannot deploy a new picklist field to a scratch org due to error: "Duplicate label"

Tags: deployment, picklist, deployment-error

We are using scratch org validation as part of our CI/CD process. I created a new custom  picklist field. When CI job deploys this field to a brand new scratch org the following error occurs:

```
Metadata Type   API Name                          Problem Type   Problem                 
   CustomField     Custom_Object__c.Country__c   Error          Duplicate label: Greece
```

This is the picklist xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Country__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Country</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
    <valueSet>
        <restricted>true</restricted>
        <valueSetDefinition>
            <sorted>false</sorted>
            <value>
                <fullName>DE</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <isActive>true</isActive>
                <label>Germany</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>FR</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <isActive>true</isActive>
                <label>France</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>PL</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Poland</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>GR</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <isActive>true</isActive>
                <label>Greece</label>
            </value>
        </valueSetDefinition>
    </valueSet>
</CustomField>
```

I found these articles [Error 'Duplicate Values' for a new, unique picklist value](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387973&type=1) and [Error 'Duplicate values' error on adding a picklist value to a field](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382802&type=1) but none of them really helped to solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: there is no issue with metadata file. by any chance this field is already there in scratch org and greece label exist already for some other picklist value api name?

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. We use a pool of pre-created scratch orgs in CI. And because this picklist existed in version control the pool was created using the old picklist (with full country names in label and api). When I updated the api name of picklist items the CI validation failed. To fix it I also updated the picklist items label.